# List of filters for sales order API

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, soap-api-v2, api-filter

I'm working with the Magento SOAP API. Many of the methods will list entites and allow for filtering in the request - however I can find no information in the documentation about what filters are available to use.

I've found some documentation about the kinds of *operators* we can use, but I'm left guessing at the field names themselves. Perhaps this is considered obvious for Magento developers, but I have little familarity with the Magento core.

Is there a list anywhere of the various fields that can be used for filtering? Specifically I'm looking for sales order filters at present, but ideally I'd like a comprehensive list of every field that can be filtered on every API method that allows filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to definitively answer this question. In the Magento core, filters tie either to attributes or database columns. Attributes are store-specific, and there's no definitive list of what each store will or will not have. The best way to discover the attributes in your store is to look in the admin panel "Manage attributes" page.

Database columns can also differ somewhat from store to store, but not as much. I suggest looking in your store's database to see what columns map to what entities.

If you have any other, more specific questions, please let me know in the comments!

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.
I think this could be better (or, at all) explained in the API docs, and perhaps link to the database schema related to the specific funciton would be helpful! I don't have access to the DB on the Magento installation I'm working with, but I've managed to find the field I was looking for.

Comment: Yep. Magento 1 docs hardly exist. I suggest searching for a magento 1.9 database scheme diagram if it would help you

Comment: @GaryStanton also, I'm glad my answer helped! Would you be willing to accept and upvote? Thanks!